# Unable to load class 'com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException'. whenever I try to sync a project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk, jvm

I'm trying to code an Android service that runs in the background and checks a variable whenever the user opens an app.

However, when I try to Sync Project with Gradle Files, I get the following error

> Unable to load class 'com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException'.
>
> This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log
> file.

[image]

Things I tried:

1. Adding the missing component jar file to /libg - no success.
2. Running Android Studio as an Administrator - no success.
3. Deleting the gradle folder so Android Studio downloads it again - no success.
4. Adding `implementation 'com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.55'` to the dependencies.

Comment: Have you tried to compile the project using Gradle command without Android Studio? As the error message indicates this can be a bug of Android Studio. Also check logs of installed anti virus system, may be the Jat file has been quarantined because it is accidentally detected as malicious.

Comment: @Robert I disabled the antivirus, and ran `gradlew.bat build`, but still no luck, unfortunately.